# Git bisect with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline, git-bisect

Jenkins 2.X got really nice - wonder if it is now somehow possible to do a git bisect with it. Currently commits are bundled to jobs depending on when jenkins saw then - which is OK when the job passes. But when the job fails it would be good if jenkins could go back in bisect style to find the breaking commit. Ideally the Jenkinsfile stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this question while looking for a solution for it myself (a year later after it was asked). I couldn't find any (easy) solution for this problem. So I created a plugin that solved the problem for us.

It's probably already irrelevant for your case, but this question is the first to pop when you Google for this, so I hope it will help others that come across this question.

You may want to check out this plugin - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Bisect+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be implemented yet (at least in Jenkins 2.14). There is an issue for [auto-bisect in Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12972), that was created back in 2012...

Comment: But this issue isn't related to the _Pipeline_ plugins.